# mysql server log file is increasing in size with warnings

Tags: mysql, max-allowed-packet

**Version:** Mysql server version is 8.0 and it is installed on Windows server 2019.

**Problem statement**: Error log file from location C:\programdata\mysql80\data\ is increasing and it is about ~100GB.
Error log statements are :

> [Warning] [MY-011959] [InnoDB] Difficult to find free blocks in the buffer pool (6091 search iterations)! 6091 failed attempts to flush a page! Consider increasing the buffer pool size. It is also possible that in your Unix version fsync is very slow, or completely frozen inside the OS kernel. Then upgrading to a newer version of your operating system may help. Look at the number of fsyncs in diagnostic info below. Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0. 1738 OS file reads, 217 OS file writes, 45 OS fsyncs. Starting InnoDB Monitor to print further diagnostics to the standard output.

**Scenario:**

1. There was failure to update more than 4MB data size to the database, so we changed the "max_allowed_packet" from default 4M to 256M in "mysql.ini" file.
2. After this settings restarted mysqld service, everything worked after this db changed.
3. But after 2 days we are facing the above mentioned issue, as a result disk space is getting full and DB connections are pending in a queue.
4. Tried to stop the mysql80 service and deleted the error.log file and reverted the max_allowed_packet to its default size.
5. But with the change also error file is getting created again with same warning.

What could be the possible issues or fix for it?

Comment: you get a hint for exampole to increase the bufferpool_size do it and such messages disappear ans also most of the other

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM is available to MySQL?

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size=8M and RAM is 16 GB